# pandas combine two strings ignore nan values

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have two columns with strings. I would like to combine them and ignore `nan` values. Such that:

```
ColA, Colb, ColA+ColB
str   str    strstr
str   nan    str
nan   str    str
```

I tried `df['ColA+ColB'] = df['ColA'] + df['ColB']` but that creates a nan value if either column is nan. I've also thought about using `concat`.

I suppose I could just go with that, and then use some `df.ColA+ColB[df[ColA] = nan] = df[ColA]` but that seems like quite the workaround.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Call [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) and pass an empty str as the fill value and then [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) with param `axis=1`:

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asd',np.NaN,'asdsa'], 'b':['asdas','asdas',np.NaN]})
df

Out[3]:
       a      b
0    asd  asdas
1    NaN  asdas
2  asdsa    NaN

In [7]:
df['a+b'] = df.fillna('').sum(axis=1)
df

Out[7]:
       a      b       a+b
0    asd  asdas  asdasdas
1    NaN  asdas     asdas
2  asdsa    NaN     asdsa
```

Answer (score 32):

You could fill the NaN with an empty string:

```
df['ColA+ColB'] = df['ColA'].fillna('') + df['ColB'].fillna('')
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `apply` and `str.cat` you can

```
In [723]: df
Out[723]:
       a      b
0    asd  asdas
1    NaN  asdas
2  asdsa    NaN

In [724]: df['a+b'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=''), axis=1)

In [725]: df
Out[725]:
       a      b       a+b
0    asd  asdas  asdasdas
1    NaN  asdas     asdas
2  asdsa    NaN     asdsa
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I wanted to join more than 2 columns together with a separator (a+b+c)

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asd',np.NaN,'asdsa'], 'b':['asdas','asdas',np.NaN], 'c':['as',np.NaN ,'ds']})

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
       a      b   c
0    asd  asdas   as
1    NaN  asdas   NaN
2  asdsa    NaN   ds
```

The following syntax worked for me:

```
In [5]: df['d'] = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].fillna('').agg('|'.join, axis=1)

In [6]: df

Out[6]:
      a      b    c             d
0    asd  asdas   as  asd|asdas|as
1    NaN  asdas  NaN       |asdas|
2  asdsa    NaN   ds     asdsa||ds
```

Comment: why not include the code to create the df and the output of the solution?

Comment: added input and output

Answer (score 4):

Prefer adding the columns than use `apply` method. cuz it's faster than `apply`.

- Just add the two columns (if you know they are strings)

  ```
  %timeit df.bio + df.procedure_codes
  ```

  21.2 ms ± 1.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
- Use apply

  ```
  %timeit df[eventcol].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
  ```

  13.6 s ± 343 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- Use Pandas string methods and cat:

  ```
  %timeit df[eventcol[0]].str.cat(cols, sep=',')
  ```

  264 ms ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- Using sum (which concatenate strings)

  ```
  %timeit df[eventcol].sum(axis=1)
  ```

  509 ms ± 6.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

see [here](http://datahans.blogspot.com/2017/08/the-fast-way-to-join-string-columns-in.html) for more tests