# Pandas combine multiple columns (with NoneType)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My apologies if this has been asked/answered before but I couldn't find this an answer to my problem after some time searching.

Very simply put I would like to combine multiple columns to one seperated with a ,
The problem is that some cells are empty (NoneType)

And when combining them I get either:

1. TypeError: ('sequence item 3: expected str instance, NoneType found', 'occurred at index 0')

or

2. When added .map(str), it literally adds 'None' for every NoneType value (as kinda expected)

Let's say I have a production dataframe looking like

```
     0        1        2
1   Rice
2   Beans    Rice
3   Milk     Beans   Rice
4   Sugar    Rice
```

What I would like is a single column with the values

```
    Production
1   Rice
2   Beans, Rice
3   Milk, Beans, Rice
4   Sugar, Rice
```

With some searching and tweaking I added this code:

```
testColumn = productionFrame.iloc[::].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x)), axis=1)
```

Which produces problem 1

or changed it like this:

```
testColumn = productionFrame.iloc[::].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.map(str)), axis=1)
```

Which produces problem 2

Maybe it's good to add that I'm very new and kinda exploring Pandas/Python right now. So any help or push in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: if `column 0` and `column 2` have a value and `column 1` has not what would you like to have ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas combine two strings ignore nan values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158417/pandas-combine-two-strings-ignore-nan-values)

Comment: @J.Doe In my DataFrame it's impossible to have NoneTypes inbetween values. But for the sake of it happening, I would still want the same end result. "column0, column2" where column1 is just left out because it's a NoneType. I hope that made sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pd.Series.str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) should work here

```
df
Out[43]: 
       0      1     2
1   Rice    NaN   NaN
2  Beans   Rice   NaN
3   Milk  Beans  Rice
4  Sugar   Rice   NaN

df.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=', '), axis=1)
Out[44]: 
1                 Rice
2          Beans, Rice
3    Milk, Beans, Rice
4          Sugar, Rice
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join` after transforming `NaN` values to empty strings:

```
res = df.fillna('').apply(lambda x: ', '.join(filter(None, x)), axis=1)

print(res)

0                 Rice
1          Beans, Rice
2    Milk, Beans, Rice
3          Sugar, Rice
dtype: object
```