# How to handle inconsistent columns of CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My CSV data looks like this:

```
ID;name;info
1;ABC;text1
2;DEF;text2;text3
3;GHI;text4;
4;JKL;text5;text6;text7
```

There are 3 named columns. The additional unnamed columns all relate to the last one (`info`), and the amount of those additional columns is not known.

Using `df=pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=";", dtype=object)` returns a `"Error tokenizing data. C error..."` due to irregular shape.

Is it possible to merge the last columns into one column containing a list, to achieve the result below?

```
ID;name;info
1;ABC;[text1]
2;DEF;[text2, text3]
3;GHI;[text4]
4;JKL;[text5, text6, text7]
```

Comment: Scan the file, identify the max number of fields (5, ie 2 more in your example), modify the fileby adding field4 and field5 in the row at the very top, and import. After that, you can combine the columns in one of many ways https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276658/pandas-combine-multiple-columns-with-nonetype

Answer (score 1):

You can read the entire file as one column, then use [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `n` (`max_split`) argument:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=None)
                         0
0             ID;name;info
1              1;ABC;text1
2        2;DEF;text2;text3
3             3;GHI;text4;
4  4;JKL;text5;text6;text7
>>> df = df[0].str.split(';', n=2, expand=True)
>>> df
    0     1                  2
0  ID  name               info
1   1   ABC              text1
2   2   DEF        text2;text3
3   3   GHI             text4;
4   4   JKL  text5;text6;text7
>>> df.columns = df.loc[0].tolist()
>>> df = df.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df['info'] = df['info'].str.strip(';').str.split(';')
>> df
  ID name                   info
0  1  ABC                [text1]
1  2  DEF         [text2, text3]
2  3  GHI                [text4]
3  4  JKL  [text5, text6, text7]
```

Alternatively,

```
>>> with open('sample.csv') as fh:
        header = next(fh).strip().split(';')
        df = pd.DataFrame([line.strip().split(';',2) for line in fh], columns=header)
>>> df['info'] = df['info'].str.strip(';').str.split(';')
>>> df
  ID name                   info
0  1  ABC                [text1]
1  2  DEF         [text2, text3]
2  3  GHI                [text4]
3  4  JKL  [text5, text6, text7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general way where we count the number of delimiters in the columns and based on that construct the dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv("text.csv")
n_sep = data.columns[0].count(";")
headers = data.columns.str.split(";")[0]

data[headers] = data.iloc[:, 0].str.split(";", n=n_sep, expand=True)
data = data.iloc[:, 1:].assign(info=data['info'].str.split(";"))
```

```
  ID name                   info
0  1  ABC                [text1]
1  2  DEF         [text2, text3]
2  3  GHI              [text4, ]
3  4  JKL  [text5, text6, text7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `pd.read_csv` expects the number of fields to be constant in a file. But the standard csv module does not. So you could use:

```
with open(filename) as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter=';')
    fn = next(rd)  # extract the headers line
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd, delimiter=';', fieldnames=fn[:-1], restkey=fn[-1])
    df = pd.DataFrame((row for row in rd), columns = fn)
```

It gives:

```
  ID name                   info
0  1  ABC                [text1]
1  2  DEF         [text2, text3]
2  3  GHI              [text4, ]
3  4  JKL  [text5, text6, text7]
```

The main drawback is that the csv module keeps everything as strings, so `df.dtypes` is:

```
ID      object
name    object
info    object
dtype: object
```