# How to merge String columns with Null

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4], 'val1':['21','22','3','35'], 
                   'val2':['99',None,'91','67'], 'val3':['21','45','76','88']})
```

I want to merge all the values of columns starting with `val` into single column.

**Expected Output**:

```
    id val1  val2 val3       val                                                                                                       
0   1   21    99   21  21,99,21                                                                                                       
1   2   22  None   45     22,45                                                                                                       
2   3    3    91   76   3,91,76                                                                                                       
3   4   35    67   88  35,67,88
```

**What I Tried:**

```
df['val'] = df['val1']+","+df['val2']+","+df['val3']
```

Which works well if there's no Null value but if row contains `None` it makes entire row `NaN`

```
   id val1  val2 val3       val                                                                                                       
0   1   21    99   21  21,99,21                                                                                                       
1   2   22  None   45       NaN                                                                                                       
2   3    3    91   76   3,91,76                                                                                                       
3   4   35    67   88  35,67,88
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas combine two strings ignore nan values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158417/pandas-combine-two-strings-ignore-nan-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply` with `dropna`:

```
df['val'] = df[['val1',  'val2', 'val3']].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
#alternative, thanks Jon Clements
#df['val'] = df.filter(regex='^val').apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
print (df)

   id val1  val2 val3       val
0   1   21    99   21  21;99;21
1   2   22  None   45     22;45
2   3    3    91   76   3;91;76
3   4   35    67   88  35;67;88
```

Alternative if performance is important is use nested list comprehension:

```
df['val'] = [';'.join(y for y in x if isinstance(y, str))
                           for x in  df.filter(regex='^val').values]
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. Is there an alternate way to select only columns starting with prefix `val`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `df.filter(like='val')`

Comment: @yatu or `df.filter(regex='^val')` to only include those that start with `val` rather than ones that contain `val`...

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You can try filling the null values:

```
df['val'] = df.fillna('')['val1']+","+df.fillna('')['val2']+","+df.fillna('')['val3']

id val1  val2 val3       val                                                                                                       
0   1   21    99   21  21,99,21                                                                                                       
1   2   22  None   45    22,,45                                                                                                       
2   3    3    91   76   3,91,76                                                                                                       
3   4   35    67   88  35,67,88
```

Comment: @jezrael yes, I have

Comment: `22,,45` I think

Comment: @jezrael What about it?

Comment: @MohitMotwani I don't want that extra `,` in that row `22,,45`